# Run a script after login that prints to the terminal a welcome message?

Tags: ubuntu, startup

I want a script that writes to the terminal a welcome message (something like echo "welcome, usr. Linux version..." etc). I have the script written, it works (i.e. it has execute privileges) so I know that's not the issue. I have tried adding it to the /etc/profile.d, /etc/update_motd, and adding the script to the startup programs, as well as using cron, with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Changing profile only affects the basically sh/bash/ksh/zsh...Not csh/tcsh type of shells.

Comment: Put it into `.bashrc` , maybe as a function, and call that function at the end of the file

Comment: For `ssh` sessions as well? Also are you sure the output of the message already works? `/etc/profile` might be also a location you could use but that e.g. `/etc/profile.d` didn't work for you is strange.